# Geokit error - "uninitialized constant"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geokit

I followed the install steps to the letter to get Geokit working on my site.  I can do a distance calculation just fine, but when I try to render a Google map using:

```
@map = GMap.new("map")
```

It throws me this error:

```
NameError in TechsController#home

uninitialized constant TechsController::GMap
```

Anyone know why?  I have a feeling it has something to do with an API key or something.  Also, I'm fully able to do distance calculations, I just can't render the map itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install [YM4R_GM](http://tinyurl.com/yjms7x5). Geokit and the Geokit-plugin don't have support for rendering Google Maps.

YM4R_GM can be found at: `http://github.com/ewildgoose/ym4r_gm`